# Flutter webrtc Video call issue

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc

I was using Flutter webrtc for video calling. When I was using video call 1st of the time it showed a black screen on both 2 devices. Then when I try to call 2nd time the video call worked fine. But when I clean my App cash  and then try to use video call, it again shows a black screen.

Can anyone please give me some advice  how can I solve this issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdXPs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obRvd.png)

Comment: can you add the log report for the first time video call